# TUIScrollView rotate by PI / 2 issue?(TWUI)

Tags: macos, cocoa, twui

I just set a `TUITableView`'s transform:

```
self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
```

After launch, when I scroll up and down, the table just scrolls left and right. How do i fix this? What I want here is when I scroll up and down, the table should also scroll up and down.